# SQL server 2014 query update to insert XML node successful but not inserting node

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml.modify

I am trying to complete a homework assignment to create, insert, modify, and xquery a XML table. I've so far been able to create the table and insert some rows of data; however, I am stuck on the *modified* portion. I have the query created and it executes successfully, but it does not insert the new **materials** node. I have to insert this child node under all **feature** nodes.

```
    CREATE TABLE Prod_Catalog
(
ID int NOT NULL Primary Key,
xCol xml NOT NULL,
)
```

-

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Prod_Catalog VALUES 
(1,'<root><productdescription ProductID="P5500xs" ProductName="Brava 55 TV">
        <features>Features
            <warranty>5 years</warranty>
            <maintenance>Dont hit with hammer</maintenance>
        </features></productdescription>
    </root>'),
(2,'<root><productdescription ProductID="G29-2" ProductName="Panasonic 1100Watt Microwave">
        <features>Features
            <warranty>1 year</warranty>
            <maintenance>Dont cook metal forks!</maintenance>
        </features></productdescription>
    </root>'),
(3,'<root><productdescription ProductID="LG22-XL" ProductName="LG 20 cubic refrigerator">
        <features>Features
            <warranty>1 year</warranty>
            <maintenance>Makes things cold.</maintenance>
        </features></productdescription>
    </root>')
```

-

```
UPDATE dbo.Prod_Catalog 
SET xCol.modify('insert <materials>Electronics,Glass,Flashy Lights</materials> as first into (/root/productiondescription[@ProductID=("P5500xs")]/features)[1]');
GO
```

-

```
(3 row(s) affected)
```

-

```
<root><productdescription ProductID="P5500xs" ProductName="Brava 55 TV"><features>Features<warranty>5 years</warranty><maintenance>Dont hit with hammer</maintenance></features></productdescription></root>
<root><productdescription ProductID="G29-2" ProductName="Panasonic 1100Watt Microwave"><features>Features<warranty>1 year</warranty><maintenance>Dont cook metal forks!</maintenance></features></productdescription></root>
<root><productdescription ProductID="LG22-XL" ProductName="LG 20 cubic refrigerator"><features>Features<warranty>1 year</warranty><maintenance>Makes things cold.</maintenance></features></productdescription></root>
```

-

Any advise or direction to get this to **truly** work is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `productiondescription` isn't an element name. `productdescription` is.

Answer (score 0):

productiondescription isn't an element name. productdescription is. –  Damien_The_Unbeliever 13 hours ago

Damien,

That did it. Thank you for the second pair of eyes.

JHG